# Why doesn't Nuxt automaticallly generate my static routes?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

All I see in `/dist` folder upon doing `npm run generate` is one `200.html` and a `_nuxt` folder with a bunch of other files: no `index.html` and no `/about` folder for my `about` route.

So `Nuxt` didn't generate my static routes and the app doesn't work.

What am I missing here?

`router.js`:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(Router)

export function createRouter () {
  return new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
      {
        path: '/',
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "index" */ '~/pages/index.vue').then(m => m.default || m)
      },
      {
        path: '/about',
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '~/pages/about.vue').then(m => m.default || m)
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

`nuxt.config.js`:

```js
export default {
  target: 'static',
  ssr: true,
  components: true,
  ...
}
```

EDIT: if I delete `router.js`, hence letting `Nuxt.js` do its automatic routing thing, then my static routes do get generated, I've just discovered. Why does it fail in the presence of `router.js`?

Comment: What is your version of nuxt ? This one should be done automatically thanks to the crawler. https://nuxtjs.org/blog/going-full-static/#crawler-integrated

Comment: Yes exactly it should be done automatically. My version of Nuxt is: `2.15.2`.

Comment: I think static files and folders don't work with ssr=true, try it with ssr=false.

Comment: @4ern thanks, same result though.

Comment: @4ern this is totally unrelated. Btw, the crawler was aimed toward static generation, so it should 100% with SSR set to true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the docs here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/file-system-routing#extending-the-router

If you do pass a `router.js` file to your Nuxt, it will overwrite your configuration due to the `@nuxtjs/router` module. You need to choose between the 2.

I'd still recommend using the Nuxt way and handle it with your files/folders and let the crawler do it's job.

Otherwise, you could maybe use the [`keepDefaultRouter`](https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-module#keepdefaultrouter) option of the router module.

For my usage, [router-extras-module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-extras-module) is good enough in terms of features: if you want to make some aliases or renaming. I do recommend it !